# EXIF Orientation problem when generating PDF with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, svg, puppeteer

I have a tool to document special plans.
I upload an image from my Smartphone with EXIF orientation data.

The plan is generated as HTML with snapSVG. I show a preview of the HTML and the image is correct.

But when I put the HTML to a page of a puppeteer chromium Browser and save it as a PDF the Image has the wrong orientation.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: @KJ It was a Chromium Bug, an update fixed the problem. I have no exif hints in the pdf, but the image itself. We generate a PDF with images, which are uploaded by the user. And so it had a worng orientation on the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade puppeteer which includes a Chromium update. This was a Chormium bug.